Disable terminal switch focus shortcut (Cmd+Left/Right Arrow)
If I have multiple Terminal windows open, and I press ⌘+Left Arrow or ⌘+Right Arrow, it will switch to another open window.
Is there a way to disable this? I'm always hitting them by accident instead of ⌥+Left/Right Arrow, which is particularly annoying with multiple desktops open given the dramatic swoop.

I could not find a menu item that I could disable in the Terminal app specifically for Cmd+Left or Cmd+Right, so in this case you can just create a Shortcut that does nothing and is triggered by Cmd+Left or Cmd+Right.
Here's what I mean:

With the above App Shortcut, by assigning it to run with the Cmd+Right Arrow key binding, you essentially override the default behaviour, which in your case is to switch between Terminal windows.
Here is also a link to the shortcut: Apple Shortcut

Good idea, but wouldn't your shortcut disable Command+Right for all apps? I would recommend using Automator instead of Shortcuts (if I remember correctly, Automator lets you restrict the app scope of a service).
